# How to add filter after completely OAuth2 authenticate in Spring Boot Security?

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to do something after OAuth2 Login in SpringBoot.

so I'm trying to add filter after OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth2/**", "/")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new MyFilter(), OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout();
    }
```

But, it is called three times. like this
[image]

here is my code.

Spring Security Configuration Class

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth2/**", "/")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login()
                    .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new MyFilter(), OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout();
    }
}
```

MyFilter class

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("login success.");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

why It is called three times? and what should I do?

I want to be called only once or getting any other good way.

Answer (score 0):

Most Spring authentications filters extend Springs OncePerRequestFilter class, for this very reason. You can consider using it if you only want the filter to execute once per request.
Your html page will have forms, javascript, images so when you submit your request, there is actually a number of resources being accessed, the Controller, and static content, images, js etc, each resource accessed needs to be evaluated separately.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. :) 
but, I have to use spring container. :(